# ng-class-odd not working properly

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

So, I have this controller

```
$rootScope.nhCount = 0;                

angular.forEach(data, function(value, key) {
      $rootScope.nhCount = $rootScope.nhCount + 1;
});
```

my html tries to use `ng-class-odd` and `ng-class-even` like so

```
<ul ng-class-odd="'timeline-inverted'" ng-class-even="'timeline'" >
            <li ng-repeat="nhCount in nhCount.data| orderBy:'date':true">
```

I use the css found [here](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/timeline-responsive).

It supposed to put every other block of content in the right or left side of the screen, according to the `ng-class-even / ng-class-odd`. It is not working. Even if I move the `ng-class-odd="'timeline-inverted'" ng-class-even="'timeline'"` inside the `<li>` is still not working.

How I can make this work? What am I missing here?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

ngClassOdd and ngClassEven directives can be applied only within the scope of an ngRepeat.

So you'd have to write something like this:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in items">
   <span ng-class-odd="'timeline-inverted'" ng-class-even="'timeline'">
     {{name}}
   </span>
</li>
```

Also I am not an Angular expert but something looks wrong with your ng-repeat, 2 colons in a row doesn't quite look right; `orderBy:'date':true`

Comment: The two colons is fine, it means call the `orderBy` filter with the two parameters `'date'` and `true`. Equivalent to calling `orderByFilter(nhCount.data, 'date', true)` in Javascript code.

Answer (score 2):

use $even and $odd variable

```js
var app = angular.module("app",[]);

app.controller("MyCtrl" , function($scope){
    
   $scope.items = [1,2,3,4,5];
  
  });
```

```css
.timeline{
  background-color: yellow;
  color : red;
  }
.timeline-inverted{
  background-color: green;
  color : red;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="app" ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <li ng-repeat="item in items">
     <span ng-class="{'timeline': $even, 'timeline-inverted': $odd}">
       {{item}}
      </span>
    </li>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think OrderBy filter is messing up the respective ng-class-odd/ng-class-even

use track by

```
<li ng-repeat="nhCount in nhCount.data| orderBy:'date':true track by $index">
```