# alternate style <ul> element in angular without ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

I want to alternatively style the `<li>`

```
    <ul ng-class-even="'even''">
     <li>
         <span>foo Span even</span>
         <p>foo p even</p>
     </li>
     <li>
         <span>foo span odd</span>
         <p>foo p odd</p>
      </li>
 </ul>
```

I want every even `<li>` tag to get styles . I tried something like this but obviously it won't work.

Comment: Your question is not very clear can you tell us what you want exactly to do ?

Comment: this may be help you http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35601165/ng-class-odd-not-working-properly/35601481#35601481

Comment: what I meant is ... is it possible to use ng-class-odd on static <ul> without ng-repeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use directive in this case, if you strictly want to use angularjs else css can also suffice

```
 <ul foo-directive odd-class='odd' even-class ='even'>
 <li>
     <span>foo Span even</span>
     <p>foo p even</p>
 </li>
 <li>
     <span>foo span odd</span>
     <p>foo p odd</p>
  </li>
</ul>
```

and directive goes like

```
    app.directive('fooDirective',function(){

        return {
            restirct:'EA',
            link:function(scope,element,attr){

                for (var i = 0; i < element[0].children.length; i++) {
                        if(i % 2 == 0)
                        element[0].children[i].className = attr.evenClass
                        else
                        element[0].children[i].className = attr.oddClass
                    }
            }

        }

    })
```

Answer (score 2):

```
li { background: green; }
li:nth-child(odd) { background: red; }
```

[> https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080699/using-css-even-and-odd-pseudo-classes-with-list-items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5080699/using-css-even-and-odd-pseudo-classes-with-list-items)

Comment: That's the most christmas table if I've ever seen one.

Comment: Yep. Just use css. There's no need to use angular when you're already typing out the whole list in html anyway.